# Efficiency of paper and pencil division

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity

I am trying to understand why the second paragraph under the stated division algorithm seems to mention the verification of one of the values for $q_i$ takes $O(l)$ time, while I think it would take $O(k)$ (checking $q_i$ in one of the inequalities that define the floor function seems to take $O(k)$ time, taking into consideration that before this algorithm we are given addition and subtraction algorithms in $O(\max(k,l)$) time and an algorithm for multiplication in $O(kl)$ time, for two integers of $k$ and $l$ digits, respectively).

[image]

Source: page 58 of Victor Shoup's free book "A computational introduction to number theory and algebra".

Comment: I think you’re right, but it’s not essential. They’re just saying that trying lots of things has bad complexity, so don’t do it.

Comment: During the steps of division, you consider $\mathcal l$ bits of the divisor at a time, as the low order bits temporarily play no role. Hence $O(\mathcal l)$ is correct.

Comment: Please elaborate, I do not understand what steps you mean, nor why you only look at l bits at a time.

Comment: Perform an ordinary written division (decimal).

Comment: I assume you meant the dividend, then.  I think I understand what you mean and I appreciate the insight.. didn't think that this brute-force approach is actually what we do on paper when 'guessing' the current digit of the quotient. Still, it is hard for me to relate my thought process while doing a division on paper to this :(.. I would really appreciate a formal proof of this complexity.

Comment: @PhantomR: ooops, yes, I meant the dividend.

Answer (score 1):

> Now we could, in theory, try all possible choices for $q_i$

means to construct the table
$$  0\cdot B^i b, 1 \cdot B^i b, \dots, (B-1) \cdot B^i b  \text{,} $$
by repeated addition, requiring $O(B-1)$ additions of size either $\ell+1$ or $\ell+i+1$.  (The "$+1$" is to manage the carries into the $B^\ell$ digit of the accumulation.  We only include the "$+i$" if we must explicitly include the trailing $i$ zeroes in the addition instead of producing them directly afterwards -- that is we already know every item on that list has (at least) $i$ trailing zeroes, so we need send them to the adder, we can just extend the adder's result by these zeroes.)  For this list, $i$ and $1$ are constant, so $O((B-1)\ell)$ bit operations.

Either after constructing this list, or as we construct this least, we want to know the last member of this list that is less than or equal to $r$.  This only requires comparing the $\ell+1$ (leading) bits of the table entry (because the trailing zeroes cannot compare greater than whatever bits are in the tail of $r$).  This is also $O((B-1)\ell)$.

Taken together $O(2(B-1)\ell) = O(B\ell)$ or, as the source observes, since $B$ is constant, $O(\ell)$.

---

It's baffling that you think $k$ is relevant.  The variable $a$ appears nowhere in "$q_i = \lfloor r/(B^i b) \rfloor$".

Comment: The observation that we can pretty much ignore the least significant i digits in r and the numbers in the table is so nice.. I, however, do not understand why you said we can take i as a constant.. if we have a for loop from i=1 to some p and we have O(i) work per iteration (in our case, it is more complex as we have O(B(l+i)=O(l+i)) as per your analysis), then the overall complexity is O(p^2). However, if we say work per iteration is constant, even though it depends on i, we get an invalid complexity O(p). I will  add another reply below this as I am out of space here..

Comment: (CONTINUING MY PREVIOUS REPLY ABOVE) I, however, think, it is indeed possible to make work per iteration not depending on i by computing the table for i=m-1 in its iteration and then just stripping the least significant 0 from each of the table's B entries at the start of iterations i=m-2,..,0. But building the first table takes O(m-1+l)=O(k). EDIT: Actually, can't we just make the table 0,b,2b,..,(B-1)b and at each step just make sure to only compare the most significant l+1 digits of r and this table's entries? The work for the table is just O(l) then.

Comment: @PhantomR : Your last description matches my description.